# find $\lambda$ such that the integral has a solution.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I have the integral equation:

$u(x) = f(x) + \lambda \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}u(y)dy$

I have to find $\lambda$ such that the integral has a solution.

How to approach such problems?

Comment: A good idea to approach these problems is to know what is $\;u\;$ so that the existence of the above integral can be checked...

Comment: This isn't a difficult problem as written; I think you miscopied something. Should that integral be from $0$ to $1/2$?

Comment: I double checked and there isn't any miscopying, @Omnomnomnom . The integral is from 0 to 1/2

Comment: Why have you doubted the 0-1/2? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @user3382078 I thought maybe it should have been $0$ to $x/2$ or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite this equation as 
$$
u(x) - f(x) =\lambda \int_0^{1/2}u(y)\,dy
$$
Note that since the integral does not vary over $x$, any solution $u$ must differ from $f$ by a constant.  That is, we may write $u(x) = f(x) + k$ for some constant $k$.

The question then becomes whether a suitable constant $k$ exists.

Substituting $u(x) = f(x) + k$ into the original equation, we have
$$
f(x) + k =  \lambda \int_0^{1/2} f(x)\,dx + \frac 12 \lambda k + f(x) \iff\\
\left(1 - \frac 12 \lambda \right)k = \lambda \int_0^{1/2} f(x)\,dx
$$
When $\lambda \neq 2$, the above equation may be solved for $k$.

For $\lambda = 2$, a solution exists only if $\int_0^{1/2}f(x)\,dx = 0$.